# Angular 2 iframe refused to display

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, iframe

I have text input. My goal is when I enter url then hit enter. I want to open url in iframe. But some sites return an error. Is there a way to open a web page in iframe

**Error message**
Refused to display 'https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to display https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/ in iframe as server forbids rendering the page outside of its domain name.

Response Header `X-Frame-Options` indicates from which source(s) page should be able to render. As it is set to `sameorigin` only applications from https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/ domain are allowed to display it in iframe.

This is security measure in order to prevent `clickjacking` attack which prevents users into being tricked to click something they shouldn't have.

You can find more on X-Frame-Options header on the following URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

More on clickjacking can be found here:
https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Clickjacking

Comment: Is there any alternative to iframe I tried  **<embed>** **<object>** all of these didnt work

Comment: @greenCode don't think so, otherwise it would be possible to exploit websites for malicious purposes.