# Is it possible embed another website in angular

Tags: angular, cross-domain, embed

I have created a project in angular and should embed the page in angular page. For example I would like to embed [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) in my angular page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 iframe refused to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576904/angular-2-iframe-refused-to-display)

Comment: Other than iframe any other way to include

Answer (score -1):

you can use iframes to embed another website into you page:

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
    title="Inline Frame Example"
    width="300"
    height="200"
    src="http://yahoo.com">
</iframe>
```

Comment: iFrame can include 3rd party websites but if its settings blocked to display then iframe wont work